# Regarding changing the Time and Date of Windows Server 2012 which is joined to a Domain

Tags: active-directory, sql-server

How to change Date and Time of windows Server 2012 R2(mssql 2014) joined to a Domain(windows server 2012).
If I change Time and Date of Windows server 2012 R2(Non-DC) different from DC will that able to work authenticating users on Domain Controller.
**FYI DC and Non-DC are on same network.**

Is it possible that authentication should work even after DC and Non-DC having different time stamps. Pls help me with this I really appreciate the help

Comment: AD relies quite heavily on time. Don't manually set times on devices in the AD schema, I don't even know what purpose this could serve...

Answer (score 0):

No. Don't change the date/time on a domain joined Windows machine. Authentication will break. You can change the **time zone** but not the actual time or date.

Kerberos defaults in Active Directory require the time difference to be less than 5 minutes. But regardless of the allowable time difference, still don't change the date/time on a member. Just don't.

Comment: Thank you Ryan, If I change time zone to back date do you think authentication works?

Comment: I have a requirement to back date. Is it possible by any chance and authentication should work fine

Comment: For the duration that the server has a time set greater than 5 minutes from the domain controller, authentication will be broken. As soon as the time returns to within 5 minutes from the DC, authentication will work again. **Important Caveat**: If the date is wrong for too long, the system will likely lose its trust relationship with the domain and won't be fixed after setting the date back.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted to know is there any tool that fool the Domain controller, or is there any other ways going to back in date still authentication should work

Comment: No. Perhaps if you described the reason you want to change the time on a domain member, we could suggest an alternative that doesn't require changing the time.